# Provider must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am struggling with a problem with Angular and Typescript.

```
module App {
    declare var environment;

    export var app: ng.IModule = angular.module("budgetsApp", [])..factory("Company", CompanyFactory)
        .controller('mainMenuController', MainMenuController);  



--Typescript file  
module App {
    declare var _;  //the underscore library

    export interface ICompanyResult {
        companyId: number;
        name: string;
    }

    export interface ICompanyFactoryFindResults {
        count: number;
        values: ICompanyResult[];
    }

    export class CompanyFactory {
        static $inject = ['$http'];

        private $http: any;

        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.$http = $http;
        }

        public find(searchTerm: any, limit: any): ICompanyFactoryFindResults {
            return this.$http
                .get('api/company')
                .then((result) => {
                    var results = _.filter(result.data, (item) => {
                        return item.name.search(new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i')) !== -1;
                    });
                    return {
                        count: result.data.length,
                        values: _.take(results.limit)
                    };
                });
        }
    }
};
```

Error I get in console is:

```
Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'Company' must return a value from $get factory method.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was helped by Girafa's reply after modifying the code as follows;

```
class Company {...}

function CompanyFactory () {
  return new Company();
}

...

app.factory('Company', CompanyFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Factory in angular should be registered as function. The return value of that function will be the value of factory.

You should wrap your class with a function:

```
class Company {...}

export function CompanyFactory () {
  return Company;
}

...

app.factory('Company', CompanyFactory);
```

This code is useful for cases where you need to create instances of `Company` class manually. If `Company` is singleton, register it as `service`:

```
app.service('Company', Company);
```